# Position div at cursor location

Tags: javascript, css

I'm using [this color wheel](https://github.com/bgrins/colorwheel-1k), and I want to add a `div` as the dragger. I was able to implement it. The problem is, when I add things above the color wheel. The dragger gets offseted the height amount of the thing above the color wheel

For example, if I add a div that has a height of `50px`, above the color wheel, the dragger will move along with the cursor, but it will be `50px` above the cursors position. I want it to be at the exact position of the cursor.

The relevant code that has to be changed is:

```
currentX = e.pageX - $(c).offset().left - radiusPlusOffset || currentX;
currentY = e.pageY - $(c).offset().top - radiusPlusOffset || currentY;
```

The obvious 'solution' would be to just subtract the height of the `div` above the color wheel. The problem with that is, it wouldn't be dynamic. I would have to add the height for every div. I thought `offset()` is supposed to calculate that.

How can I dynamically make the dragger `div` at the exact position of the cursor? I'd prefer doing this with bare JavaScript, not JQuery.

#### JSFiddle

```js
var b = document.body;
var c = document.createElement('canvas');
var a = c.getContext('2d');
var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
document.body.clientWidth; // fix bug in webkit: http://qfox.nl/weblog/218

var colorWheelDiv = document.createElement('div');
var dragger = document.createElement('div');
dragger.id = 'dragger';

var otherDiv = document.createElement('div');
var text = document.createTextNode('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, ');
colorWheelDiv.appendChild(c);
otherDiv.appendChild(text);
colorWheelDiv.appendChild(dragger);

wrapper.appendChild(otherDiv);
wrapper.appendChild(colorWheelDiv);

(function() {

  // Declare constants and variables to help with minification
  // Some of these are inlined (with comments to the side with the actual equation)
  var doc = document;
  doc.c = doc.createElement;
  b.a = b.appendChild;

  var width = c.width = c.height = 400,
    label = b.a(doc.c("p")),
    input = b.a(doc.c("input")),
    imageData = a.createImageData(width, width),
    pixels = imageData.data,
    oneHundred = input.value = input.max = 100,
    circleOffset = 0,
    diameter = width - circleOffset * 2,
    radius = diameter / 2,
    radiusPlusOffset = radius + circleOffset,
    radiusSquared = radius * radius,
    two55 = 255,
    currentY = oneHundred,
    currentX = -currentY,
    wheelPixel = circleOffset * 4 * width + circleOffset * 4;

  // Math helpers
  var math = Math,
    PI = math.PI,
    PI2 = PI * 2,
    sqrt = math.sqrt,
    atan2 = math.atan2;

  // Setup DOM properties
  b.style.textAlign = "center";
  label.style.font = "2em courier";
  input.type = "range";

  // Load color wheel data into memory.
  for (y = input.min = 0; y < width; y++) {
    for (x = 0; x < width; x++) {
      var rx = x - radius,
        ry = y - radius,
        d = rx * rx + ry * ry,
        rgb = hsvToRgb(
          (atan2(ry, rx) + PI) / PI2, // Hue
          sqrt(d) / radius, // Saturation
          1 // Value
        );

      // Print current color, but hide if outside the area of the circle
      pixels[wheelPixel++] = rgb[0];
      pixels[wheelPixel++] = rgb[1];
      pixels[wheelPixel++] = rgb[2];
      pixels[wheelPixel++] = d > radiusSquared ? 0 : two55;
    }
  }

  // Bind Event Handlers
  input.onchange = redraw;
  c.onmousedown = doc.onmouseup = function(e) {
    // Unbind mousemove if this is a mouseup event, or bind mousemove if this a mousedown event
    doc.onmousemove = /p/.test(e.type) ? 0 : (redraw(e), redraw);
  }

  // Handle manual calls + mousemove event handler + input change event handler all in one place.
  function redraw(e) {

    // Only process an actual change if it is triggered by the mousemove or mousedown event.
    // Otherwise e.pageX will be undefined, which will cause the result to be NaN, so it will fallback to the current value
    currentX = e.pageX - $(c).offset().left - radiusPlusOffset || currentX;
    currentY = e.pageY - $(c).offset().top - radiusPlusOffset || currentY;

    // Scope these locally so the compiler will minify the names.  Will manually remove the 'var' keyword in the minified version.
    var theta = atan2(currentY, currentX),
      d = currentX * currentX + currentY * currentY;

    // If the x/y is not in the circle, find angle between center and mouse point:
    //   Draw a line at that angle from center with the distance of radius
    //   Use that point on the circumference as the draggable location
    if (d > radiusSquared) {
      currentX = radius * math.cos(theta);
      currentY = radius * math.sin(theta);
      theta = atan2(currentY, currentX);
      d = currentX * currentX + currentY * currentY;
    }

    label.textContent = b.style.background = hsvToRgb(
      (theta + PI) / PI2, // Current hue (how many degrees along the circle)
      sqrt(d) / radius, // Current saturation (how close to the middle)
      input.value / oneHundred // Current value (input type="range" slider value)
    )[3];

    // Reset to color wheel and draw a spot on the current location. 
    a.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);

    // Draw the current spot.
    // I have tried a rectangle, circle, and heart shape.
    /*
    // Rectangle:
    a.fillStyle = '#000';
    a.fillRect(currentX+radiusPlusOffset,currentY+radiusPlusOffset, 6, 6);
    */
    /*
    // Circle:
    a.beginPath();  
    a.strokeStyle = '#000';
    a.arc(~~currentX+radiusPlusOffset,~~currentY+radiusPlusOffset, 4, 0, PI2);
    a.stroke();
    */

    // Heart:
    /*a.font = "1em arial";
    a.fillText("♥", currentX + radiusPlusOffset - 4, currentY + radiusPlusOffset + 4);*/

    dragger.style.left = (~~currentX + radiusPlusOffset) + 'px';
    dragger.style.top = (~~currentY + radiusPlusOffset) + 'px';

  }

  // Created a shorter version of the HSV to RGB conversion function in TinyColor
  // https://github.com/bgrins/TinyColor/blob/master/tinycolor.js
  function hsvToRgb(h, s, v) {
    h *= 6;
    var i = ~~h,
      f = h - i,
      p = v * (1 - s),
      q = v * (1 - f * s),
      t = v * (1 - (1 - f) * s),
      mod = i % 6,
      r = [v, q, p, p, t, v][mod] * two55,
      g = [t, v, v, q, p, p][mod] * two55,
      b = [p, p, t, v, v, q][mod] * two55;

    return [r, g, b, "rgb(" + ~~r + "," + ~~g + "," + ~~b + ")"];
  }

  // Kick everything off
  redraw(0);

  /*
  // Just an idea I had to kick everything off with some changing colors…
  // Probably no way to squeeze this into 1k, but it could probably be a lot smaller than this:
  currentX = currentY = 1;
  var interval = setInterval(function() {
      currentX--;
      currentY*=1.05;
      redraw(0)
  }, 7);
    
  setTimeout(function() {
      clearInterval(interval)
  }, 700)
  */

})();
```

```css
canvas {
  cursor: pointer;
}
#dragger {
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='wrapper'>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the position of the div that is containing the canvas and dragger to relative. Then the top offset will be correct. The left offset is also wrong in your calculation, it should be: 
e.pageX - $(colorWheelDiv).offset().left

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s1ue7s48/5/)

```js
var b = document.body;
var c = document.createElement('canvas');
var a = c.getContext('2d');
var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
document.body.clientWidth; // fix bug in webkit: http://qfox.nl/weblog/218

var colorWheelDiv = document.createElement('div');
var dragger = document.createElement('div');
dragger.id = 'dragger';

var otherDiv = document.createElement('div');
var text = document.createTextNode('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, ');
colorWheelDiv.appendChild(c);
otherDiv.appendChild(text);
colorWheelDiv.appendChild(dragger);
colorWheelDiv.style.position = 'relative';

wrapper.appendChild(otherDiv);
wrapper.appendChild(colorWheelDiv);

(function() {

  // Declare constants and variables to help with minification
  // Some of these are inlined (with comments to the side with the actual equation)
  var doc = document;
  doc.c = doc.createElement;
  b.a = b.appendChild;

  var width = c.width = c.height = 400,
    label = b.a(doc.c("p")),
    input = b.a(doc.c("input")),
    imageData = a.createImageData(width, width),
    pixels = imageData.data,
    oneHundred = input.value = input.max = 100,
    circleOffset = 0,
    diameter = width - circleOffset * 2,
    radius = diameter / 2,
    radiusPlusOffset = radius + circleOffset,
    radiusSquared = radius * radius,
    two55 = 255,
    currentY = oneHundred,
    currentX = -currentY,
    wheelPixel = circleOffset * 4 * width + circleOffset * 4;

  // Math helpers
  var math = Math,
    PI = math.PI,
    PI2 = PI * 2,
    sqrt = math.sqrt,
    atan2 = math.atan2;

  // Setup DOM properties
  b.style.textAlign = "center";
  label.style.font = "2em courier";
  input.type = "range";

  // Load color wheel data into memory.
  for (y = input.min = 0; y < width; y++) {
    for (x = 0; x < width; x++) {
      var rx = x - radius,
        ry = y - radius,
        d = rx * rx + ry * ry,
        rgb = hsvToRgb(
          (atan2(ry, rx) + PI) / PI2, // Hue
          sqrt(d) / radius, // Saturation
          1 // Value
        );

      // Print current color, but hide if outside the area of the circle
      pixels[wheelPixel++] = rgb[0];
      pixels[wheelPixel++] = rgb[1];
      pixels[wheelPixel++] = rgb[2];
      pixels[wheelPixel++] = d > radiusSquared ? 0 : two55;
    }
  }

  // Bind Event Handlers
  input.onchange = redraw;
  c.onmousedown = doc.onmouseup = function(e) {
    // Unbind mousemove if this is a mouseup event, or bind mousemove if this a mousedown event
    doc.onmousemove = /p/.test(e.type) ? 0 : (redraw(e), redraw);
  }

  // Handle manual calls + mousemove event handler + input change event handler all in one place.
  function redraw(e) {

    // Only process an actual change if it is triggered by the mousemove or mousedown event.
    // Otherwise e.pageX will be undefined, which will cause the result to be NaN, so it will fallback to the current value
    currentX = e.pageX - $(c).offset().left - radiusPlusOffset || currentX;
    currentY = e.pageY - $(c).offset().top - radiusPlusOffset || currentY;

    // Scope these locally so the compiler will minify the names.  Will manually remove the 'var' keyword in the minified version.
    var theta = atan2(currentY, currentX),
      d = currentX * currentX + currentY * currentY;

    // If the x/y is not in the circle, find angle between center and mouse point:
    //   Draw a line at that angle from center with the distance of radius
    //   Use that point on the circumference as the draggable location
    if (d > radiusSquared) {
      currentX = radius * math.cos(theta);
      currentY = radius * math.sin(theta);
      theta = atan2(currentY, currentX);
      d = currentX * currentX + currentY * currentY;
    }

    label.textContent = b.style.background = hsvToRgb(
      (theta + PI) / PI2, // Current hue (how many degrees along the circle)
      sqrt(d) / radius, // Current saturation (how close to the middle)
      input.value / oneHundred // Current value (input type="range" slider value)
    )[3];

    // Reset to color wheel and draw a spot on the current location. 
    a.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);

    // Draw the current spot.
    // I have tried a rectangle, circle, and heart shape.
    /*
    // Rectangle:
    a.fillStyle = '#000';
    a.fillRect(currentX+radiusPlusOffset,currentY+radiusPlusOffset, 6, 6);
    */
    /*
    // Circle:
    a.beginPath();  
    a.strokeStyle = '#000';
    a.arc(~~currentX+radiusPlusOffset,~~currentY+radiusPlusOffset, 4, 0, PI2);
    a.stroke();
    */

    // Heart:
    /*a.font = "1em arial";
    a.fillText("♥", currentX + radiusPlusOffset - 4, currentY + radiusPlusOffset + 4);*/

    dragger.style.left = (e.pageX - $(colorWheelDiv).offset().left) + 'px';
    dragger.style.top = (~~currentY + radiusPlusOffset) + 'px';

  }

  // Created a shorter version of the HSV to RGB conversion function in TinyColor
  // https://github.com/bgrins/TinyColor/blob/master/tinycolor.js
  function hsvToRgb(h, s, v) {
    h *= 6;
    var i = ~~h,
      f = h - i,
      p = v * (1 - s),
      q = v * (1 - f * s),
      t = v * (1 - (1 - f) * s),
      mod = i % 6,
      r = [v, q, p, p, t, v][mod] * two55,
      g = [t, v, v, q, p, p][mod] * two55,
      b = [p, p, t, v, v, q][mod] * two55;

    return [r, g, b, "rgb(" + ~~r + "," + ~~g + "," + ~~b + ")"];
  }

  // Kick everything off
  redraw(0);

  /*
  // Just an idea I had to kick everything off with some changing colors…
  // Probably no way to squeeze this into 1k, but it could probably be a lot smaller than this:
  currentX = currentY = 1;
  var interval = setInterval(function() {
      currentX--;
      currentY*=1.05;
      redraw(0)
  }, 7);

  setTimeout(function() {
      clearInterval(interval)
  }, 700)
  */

})();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The only problem with that, is if you scroll down, (either add more content to the top; make the browser size larger; or make the jsfiddles result smaller) the dragger is at a fixed position. It stays at the same position even when you scroll.

Comment: You are right, I updated the answer. Now it works also with scrolling. If the window is resized you would have to calculate the position again.

Comment: Thanks! Can you please explain why "The left offset is also wrong in your calculation, it should be: e.pageX - $(colorWheelDiv).offset().left"

Comment: To get the left offset for the dragger inside the colorWheelDiv you need to take the pageX of the mousemove event and subtract the left offset of the colorWheelDiv. I am not sure what exactly your calculation was, but when I tested it the dragger was placed appr. 100px to the left of the cursor. Just check your original JSFiddle, you will see that the dragger does not only have a top offset but also a left offset from the cursor position.